# Re-executing Javascript every route in Meteor / Flow Router?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I have a code in my theme that appends a background  as a CSS background. Here's the JS code:

```
$('.background-image-holder').each(function() {
    var imgSrc = $(this).children('img').attr('src');
    $(this).css('background', 'url("' + imgSrc + '")');
    $(this).children('img').hide();
    $(this).css('background-position', 'initial');
});

// Fade in background images

setTimeout(function() {
    $('.background-image-holder').each(function() {
        $(this).addClass('fadeIn');
    });
}, 200);
```

Now the issue is this code works everytime I refresh the page, but not so much when I click from one route to the next.

E.g. I refresh the index page and the cover image loads, but if I click the about page then the images on the about page no longer load... unless I refresh the page. I'm currently executing the code using the .onRendered method:

```
Template.mainIndex.onRendered(function(){ ...code here });
```

Is there anyway I can have this script re-execute on every load, or is there a better way to resolve this issue? I'm using Flow Router, and Blaze Layout on Meteor JS.

Comment: Have you thought about inlining the style and using helpers to generate the dynamic parts?

Answer (score 0):

`FlowRouter` has triggers: https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router#triggers

```
FlowRouter.triggers.enter([cb1, cb2]);
FlowRouter.triggers.exit([cb1, cb2]);
```